# Cannot display ffprobe information from youtube properly

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffprobe

I am trying to grab information from youtube streams using ffprobe and python. I could display offline video information properly on python, cannot do the same from youtube live streams.

```
os.system("ffprobe -hide_banner -stats -v quiet -pretty -show_entries format=size,duration:stream=filename,index,codec_type,codec_name,profile,bit_rate,width,height -of compact -i https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzsfLSP6hkI")
```

showing an error

> Argument 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzsfLSP6hkI' provided as input filename, but 'quiet' was already specified.

Comment: That YouTube URL is not a direct link to a video.

Comment: How to get that direct link? sorry i am bit confused

Comment: You should probably use youtube-dl.

Comment: @llogan what is that, and how to get it? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: See [youtube-dl.org](https://youtube-dl.org/)